# Why doesn't closing div tag work no matter where I put it?

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes, tumblr-html

I feel a bit silly posting this, since I've been working on this code for a bit and have run into this problem before, but in trying to clean up this project I removed/misplaced **something** and now my blog layout will not behave the way I want it to. I have two divs, one acting as the main container div, and another one inside that div for the actual blog entries. I'm *almost* sure it's a missing  tag, but no matter where I place the closing tag, it doesn't look like what it initially did, so now I'm not entirely sure. The closest I get it almost ends up looking normal, but the embedded media content and tags do not appear. Here is my html markup; I can't figure it out for the life of me. Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- MAIN BLOG CONTAINER -->
<div class="pc">
{block:Posts}

            <!-- POSTNOTES -->
            <div class="pnc">
            {block:Date}
            <a href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth} {ShortYear}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            {block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}&nbsp;
            {block:RebloggedFrom}
            <a href="{ReblogParentURL}" ="{ReblogParentName}"></a>
            <a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootName}">source</a>
            {/block:RebloggedFrom}
            {/block:Date}
            </div>
            <!-- END OF POSTNOTES -->

            <!-- PERMALINK -->
            {block:PermalinkPage}
            {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}{/block:PostNotes}
            {/block:PermalinkPage}
            <!-- END OF PERMALINK -->

            <!-- POST TITLE CONTAINER -->
            {block:Title}
            <div class="ptc">
                <div class="pt">{Title}</div>
            </div>
            {/block:Title}
            <!-- END OF POST TITLE CONTAINER -->

            <!-- INSIDE OF POSTS -->
            <div class="posts">
            {block:Text}
            {Body}
            {/block:Text}
            </div>

                <!-- PHOTOS -->
                <!-- SINGLE PHOTO -->
                {block:Photo}
                <center>
                <div style="margin-top:10px"></div>
                <img src="{PhotoURL-250}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">
                </center>
                {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{
                /block:Photo}
                <!-- END OF SINGLE PHOTO -->

                <!-- PHOTOSET -->
                {block:Photoset}
                <div style="margin-top:10px"></div>
                <center>{Photoset-250}</center>
                {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                {/block:Photoset}
                <!-- END OF PHOTOSET -->

                <!-- PANAROMA -->
                {block:Panorama}
                {LinkOpenTag}
                <img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/>
                {LinkCloseTag}
                {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                {/block:Panorama}
                <!-- END OF PANAROMA -->

                <!-- ASKS -->
                {block:Answer}
                <img src="{AskerPortraitURL-64}">
                {Asker}:
                {Question}
                {Answer}
                {/block:Answer}
                <!-- END OF ASKS -->

                <!-- VIDEOS -->
                {block:Video}
                <center>
                <div style="margin-top:10px"></div>
                {Video-250}
                </center>
                {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                {/block:Video}
                <!-- END OF VIDEOS -->

                <!-- QUOTES -->
                {block:Quote}
                {Quote}
                {block:Source}
                <div class="source">{Source}</div>
                {/block:Source}
                {/block:Quote}
                <!-- END OF QUOTES --> 

                <!-- LINKS -->
                {block:Link}
                <a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name}</a>
                {block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
                {/block:Link}
                <!-- LINKS -->

                <!-- CHAT -->
                {block:Chat}
                {block:Title}{Title}{/block:Title}
                {block:Lines}
                {block:Label}{Label}{/block:Label}
                {Line}
                {/block:Lines}
                {/block:Chat}
                <!-- END OF CHAT -->

                <!-- AUDIO -->
                {block:Audio}
                <div style="margin-top:10px;"></div>
                <center>
                {AudioPlayerWhite}
                {block:AlbumArt}<img src="{AlbumArtURL}">{/block:AlbumArt}
                <p>{block:TrackName}{TrackName}{/block:TrackName}</br>
                {block:Artist} {Artist}{/block:Artist}</br>
                </center>
                {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                {/block:Audio}
                <!-- END OF AUDIO -->
                </div>

                <!-- TAGS -->
                <div class="tc">
                    <div class="tags">
                    {block:Tags}
                    <a href="{TagURL}" id="{Tag}">*&nbsp;{Tag}</a>
                    {/block:Tags}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END OF TAGS -->

    {/block:Posts}
    </div>
    <!-- END OF MAIN BLOG CONTAINER -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi NR che your  <p> this is open, but never close

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the solution, unfortunately.

Comment: can you share your page? to inspect the code. It could be a css attribute

Comment: @RobertoVargas I've included the pastebin in the post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE*** Figured as much; it was an open bracket from one of the blocks. I had accidentally indented it, thus creating an open space, and it messed up the entire layout:

```
        <!-- PHOTOS -->
        <!-- SINGLE PHOTO -->
        {block:Photo}
        <center>
        <div style="margin-top:10px"></div>
        <img src="{PhotoURL-250}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">
        </center>
        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}{
        /block:Photo}
        <!-- END OF SINGLE PHOTO -->
```